# SQL Server - Partition Table with hierarchyid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data, hierarchyid

Is there any limitation with tables that contain hierarchyid columns? Does it limit any of the functionality like partitioning etc? I can't seem to find anything that says there is, but wanted to check with some of the more experienced users to see if I am looking over something.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to partition hierarchyid column values. If you try to execute something like the bellow query then you will get error "The type 'hierarchyid' is not valid for this operation"

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION MyPartitionRange (hierarchyid) AS RANGE 
    LEFT FOR VALUES ('/20140101/','/20150101/','/20160101/')  
GO
```